# check the copying in directory in shell

Tags: shell

I have created a script which pick the files from a directory `inbox`. I have to include a handling in the script whether files are coming from another process or not. if files are coming through another process then my script should wait until files are copied.

For this i have create a flag

```
CHECK_COPY_PROCESS=$(ps -ef|grep -E 'cp|mv|scp'|grep inbox)
```

if flag `CHECK_COPY_PROCESS` contains some value then process will go to waiting state. but problem is that suppose some files are coming from sub directory of that directory `inbox`
then process will generate like this `cp file_name ..` above logic is not working.

Comment: You could also use `lsof` but I am not sure that there is a bullet-proof solution; maybe also `inotify`

Comment: Thanks Basile for your response, lof command is used for to view the open list of files. how it is relate with mv,cp,scp?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tip of Basile, using lsof in conjunction with awk (grepping only on the first column, which is the command name)

Example:

```
lsof +D /path/to/inbox|awk '$1~/mv|cp|scp/'
```

This is not tested as I currently don't have big files that take a while to copy on my machine.

Comment: Hi Elisiano.. this path (/path/to/inbox) is for source path but i need to identify the destination. Can you please suggest for destination path.

Comment: Try adding the +D option to the directory passed to lsof
    lsof +D /path/to/inbox|awk '$1~/mv|cp|scp/'

I will edit the original answer to reflect this